# link with full width inside div

Tags: html, css

I have a problem that I don't understand. Inside parent div I have a link and I want to fill full parent width.

```
#changePassword {
    width:100%;
    height:5.28%;
    border-bottom:1px solid #a9aaa7;
    background:#3c3c3c;
}

#changePassword a {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background:url(iconPassword.png) no-repeat;
    color:#FFF;
    font-size:1vw;
    text-decoration:none;
    padding-left:20%;
}
```

But only fill text inside link. I've test this width a border.

[image]

Comment: you'll need to add `display:block;` to `#changePassword a`

Answer (score 4):

Add `display:block` to `a` tag class

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ez5w64Lh/)**

Answer (score 4):

Anchors are inline elements which means, among other things, that they will only be as big as their contents and horizontal padding.

You can change this by changing the `display` property in CSS. In this case, you would need to set it to `block` or `inline-block`.

[More information on the `display` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display)